# Unable to click on a link present in table cell which is displayedin 2 lines

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm automating an application using NUnit Framework with C#.
Using the below code I'm able to locate & click an element whole link text displayed in single line (Ex: abcd). But I'm unable to click the link if it's displayed in 2 lines (Ex: abcd\nxyz)

// Search & Click on name link

[Image of the control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5sj1.png)

```
IWebElement table1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='tblSearchAudienceResults']/tbody")); 
IList<IWebElement> rowCollection = table1.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

foreach (IWebElement row in rowCollection)
{
    IList<IWebElement> colItem = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    Console.WriteLine("TA Name: " +colItem[1].Text);

    if (colItem[1].Text.Equals(audienceName))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Inside If");
         colItem[1].Click();
         Console.WriteLine("Clicked on Link");
         break;
    }                            
}
```

Comment: Please post the table cell text or its HTML code.

Comment: You don't need to be looping through all these cells & rows. Use an XPath selector - providing you are using a modern browser it's going to be more efficient than this.

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26845431/selecting-checkbox-in-a-table-using-selenium/26847768#26847768 it might help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Try clicking on anchor element rather than `td` - for example -

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><a href="reftosomelink">Sample long text which is multiline</a></td>
  <td>Some other label</td> 
  <td>50</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here in this case try -

```
row.FindElement(By.xpath("./td[1]/a")).click();
```

If this also does not work, please post your html and error.