# Selecting checkbox in a table using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check a Checkbox in a table, it actually able to locate the Checkbox but it does not check/click the checkbox. The selectCheckbox.Click() is not working, can somebody explain to me why it's not checking/clicking the checkbox? thanks :)

my code is like this:

```
IWebElement table = WebBrowser.Current.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));

        ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> allRows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));

        for (int z = 0; z < allRows.Count; z++)
        {
            ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> cells = allRows[z].FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

            for (int y = 0; y < cells.Count; y++)
            {
                var value = allRows[z].FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[y].Text;

                if (value.Equals(tenant))
                {
                    var selectCheckbox = allRows[z].FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[y - 1];
                    selectCheckbox.Click();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are clicking a `td`. This isn't going to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are finding the `td` tag and trying to click on it. Try changing the code as shown below to find the `input` tag (Assuming that there is only one `input` tag in the required `td`)

from

```
var selectCheckbox = allRows[z].FindElements(By.TagName("td"))[y - 1];
```

to

```
var selectCheckbox = allRows[z].FindElements(By.TagName("input"))[y - 1].FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @lost for your answer I used Id instead of TagName. :)